# limit superior of real value function (Exercise 9.3.4 in Tao Analysis I)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Here is the exercise:

> Propose a definition for limit superior $\lim\sup_{x \to x_0 ; x \in E} f(x)$ and limit inferior $\lim\inf_{x \to x_0 ; x \in E} f(x)$, and then propose an analogue of Proposition 9.3.9 for your definition.
> (For an additional challenge: prove that analogue.)

Here is Proposition 9.3.9:

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number.
> Then the following two statements are logically equivalent:
> (a). $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$.
>
> (b). For every sequence $(a_n)_{n = 0}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n = 0}^\infty$ converges to $L$.

Here is my attemped:

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, and let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$.
> We define limit superior at $x_0$ in $E$ as
> $$
>     \limsup_{x \to x_0 ; x \in E} f(x) = \inf\Big\{\sup\big\{f(x) : x \in E \land |x - x_0| < \delta\big\} : \delta \in \mathbf{R}^+\Big\}
> $$
> Let $L \in \mathbf{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$.
> We claim that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (a). $\limsup_{x \to x_0 ; x \in E} f(x) = L$
>
> (b). For every sequence $(a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n = 1}^\infty$ has limit superior $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) \leq L$
> There exists a sequence $(b_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = L$

I managed to prove (a) implies (b).
But I don't know how to prove (b) implies (a).
(Note that $L$ can be $-\infty$ or $+\infty$)
Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: How about this for b) for finite $L$:  for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, for every sequence $(a_n)\subset E-\lbrace x_0 \rbrace $, we have $f(a_n)\lt L+\epsilon $ for sufficiently large $n$ and $L-\epsilon \lt f(a_n)$ for infinite collection of $n$?

Comment: Can you give an example for why choosing such definition?

Comment: The idea comes from definition of limsup. If $\limsup x_n=s$ then for all $t\gt s$ there exists an N such that $n\ge N\implies x_n\lt t$ and for every $\epsilon\gt 0, x_n\gt s-\epsilon$ for infinite many $n$.

Comment: It make sense know, so how do we use this definition to prove that (b) implies (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\limsup _{x\rightarrow x_{0} ;x\in E} f(x)=\inf\Bigl\{\sup \bigl\{f(x):x\in E\land |x-x_{0} |< \delta \bigr\} :\delta \in \mathbf{R}^{+}\Bigr\} \tag{A}
\end{equation}

We'll prove that the following are equivalent (for $L\in \mathbb R$):

1. $\displaystyle \limsup _{E\ni x\rightarrow x_{0}} \ f( x) =L$
2. For every $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ and every sequence $\displaystyle ( x_{n}) \subset E-\{x_{0} \}$ converging to $\displaystyle x_{0}$, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle n\geq N\Longrightarrow $$\displaystyle f( x_{n}) < L+\epsilon $ and $\displaystyle f( x_{m})  >L -\epsilon $ for infinite $\displaystyle m$.

First let's consider the case when $\displaystyle \limsup _{E\ni x\rightarrow x_{0}} \ f( x)$$\displaystyle \in \mathbb{R}$. .

$\displaystyle ( 1) \Longrightarrow ( 2) :$Fix an $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$ and let $\displaystyle ( x_{n}) \subset E-\{x_{0} \}$ be any sequence converging to $\displaystyle x_{0}$.

By $\displaystyle (A) :\ \exists \ \delta  >0$ such that $\displaystyle \sup \{f( x) :\ x\in E\land |x-x_{0} |< \delta \}< L+\epsilon $

It follows that $\displaystyle x\in E\land |x-x_{0} |< \delta \Longrightarrow f( x) \leq \sup \{f( x) :\ x\in E\land |x-x_{0} |< \delta \}< L+\epsilon $

Now $\displaystyle \left( x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}\right) \ \Longrightarrow \exists N\ ( n\geq N\Longrightarrow |x_{n} -x_{0} |< \delta $)

It follows that $\displaystyle f( x_{n}) < L+\epsilon $

I leave the other part to you.

For the converse,

$\displaystyle ( 2) \Longrightarrow ( 1) :$As per our condition, $\displaystyle \limsup $ exists. Suppose it is equal to $\displaystyle r\neq L$.

If $\displaystyle r >L$, then we must have by $\displaystyle ( 1) \Longrightarrow ( 2)$ that $\displaystyle f( x_{n})  >r-( r-L) =L$ for infinitely many $\displaystyle n$, which contradicts $\displaystyle ( 2)$.

Similarly if $\displaystyle r< L$, then $\displaystyle f( x_{n})  >L-( L-r) =r$ for infinitely many $\displaystyle n$ but this contradicts the assumption that $\displaystyle r$ is a limsup.

So $\displaystyle r=L$ and we are done!

What if $\displaystyle \limsup _{E\ni x\rightarrow x_{0}} \ f( x) =+\infty $?

In that event, $\displaystyle f$ is not bounded from above in any neighborhood of $\displaystyle x_{0}$. So for every sequence $\displaystyle x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0} ,\ x_{n} \neq x_{0}$ for any $\displaystyle n$, we can find a subsequence $\displaystyle x_{n_{k}}$ such that $\displaystyle f( x_{n_{k}})\rightarrow +\infty $

Similarly, you may handle the case when $\displaystyle \limsup _{E\ni x\rightarrow x_{0}} \ f( x) =-\infty $

Comment: In the proof of $(1) \implies (2)$ you used $L + \varepsilon$ and $(2) \implies (1)$ you used $r - L$.
Does that means your proposed definition only work for the case $L \in \mathbf{R}$ but not the case $L \in \{-\infty, \infty\}$?
If that so, can we conclude that for the case $L \in \{-\infty, \infty\}$ we must come up with different definition?

Comment: Besides, your proposed definition is basically the same as my (I wrote the symbolic definition of $\lim\sup$ and you wrote the analytical definition), so I think your proposed definition might not be able to prove the case $L = -\infty$ (which I was stuck for a quite long)

Comment: I'm sorry that it's been very long, but I'm going through your answer now and I'll provide feedback at the earliest.

Comment: @Koro I think you mean "for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, there DOES exist an $N$ such that $f(x_n) < a - \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ and $f(x_n) > a + \varepsilon$ is true for finite $n$".
I agree with this definition, but what I'm asking is the definition in your comment is not the same as the definition in your post (since your post invoving "plus" and "minus" operation with $L$, but we know these operation is not well-defined when $L$ is positive or negative infinity).

Comment: I'm getting confuse of your "No". Do you mean "the plus or minus is well-defined" or else? Can you update your answer for better clarification?

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll: In my post, $L$ has been considered finite.

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll: I think your definition to handle $-\infty$ case makes sense. To that effect, I have deleted some of my earlier comments to avoid confusion and also added $L\in \mathbb R$ in my post.

Comment: So can we conclude that "we must treat finite and infinite cases seperately, in other words, we must use different definitions for L being finite, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$"?

Comment: @ProFatXuanAll: It seems so but whether it is possible or NOT for the existing definition that is (2) in this post to accommodate $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ cases, is what I am not so sure about.

Comment: I did search for such proof but get nothing. So I think it's fine to just use 2 different definitions instead. If you update your answer I will accept it. Thank you for discuss this with me.